# output issue when using ASCII convertion in Python 3.4.3

Tags: python, file, ascii, chr

I try to write the ASCII character out to a file base on the decoded input.

```
outfile = open ('output','w')
```

This one is working if using the constant value for chr()

```
c = chr(65)   << work
outfile.write(c)
```

However, this one is not working (note: i is an integer variable)

```
c = chr(i+65)  << not work
outfile.write(c)
```

It complains "UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x81' in position 0: character maps to "

After the conversion from decimal to ASCII, chr(n), should it be the character already? 
Why doesn't work?

Comment: From the error message, `i == 64`, so `i + 65` yields character `\x81` which is not in the range for ASCII characters and hence cannot be encoded.

Comment: try outfile.write(c.encode("utf-8"))

Comment: Try open file for writing bytes: `open ('output','wb')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 3, the `chr` function returns a one-character Unicode string (a `str` instance). At some point in your code, `i` is taking on the value `64`, which when you do `chr(i+65)` creates the character `'\x81'`. That's a control character, not something that can be encoded in ASCII, which is why you're getting an error when you go to write it out.

There are various ways you can go about fixing this issue, which is best will depend a great deal on what you're trying to accomplish.

The first solution would be to figure out why you're getting an `i` value of `64` and stop that from happening. This may be an off-by-one error with a `range` bound, or something else that's simple to fix.

If you really do want to write `'\x81'` to your file, another approach would be to change how you're opening your file, specifying an encoding other than the default (or opening in binary mode and handling the encoding yourself). You can also create a binary string from an integer directly with the `bytes` constructor: `bytes((i + 65,))`. Note that the argument needs to be an iterable, even if there's just one value.

Comment: Whether it's a control character depends on the encoding (it is in ISO 8859-1 but not in code page 437, for instance), but the relevant thing here is that the code point 0x81 cannot exist in ASCII at all, because ASCII is 7-bit. ASCII does have a bunch of control characters below 0x20.

Comment: The `'\x81'` I'm referring to is a one-character Unicode string, not an byte string encoded with some encoding. That Unicode character *is* a control character, with no ambiguity, since the Unicode standard duplicates ISO 8859-1 between codepoints 128 and 255 (the [Latin-1 supplement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1_Supplement_%28Unicode_block%29) block).

Comment: Oops, pardon me. Too used to Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

I add a limitation to input i.

i < 128

Now it works fine.

Thanks all for helping.